# Conformal transformation of a region bounded by a curve $y=x^a, a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry

I would like to solve the 2D Laplace equation $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} =0$ on the positive upper half plane: $0 <x<\infty$ and $0 < y < \infty$. The domain is bounded by a curve $y=x^a,a>1, a \in \mathbb{R}$ on the left hand side. Which complex transformation can map this domain to a simple unit circle or any easily solveable domain?

Comment: I'm afraid there is none that one can realistically write down. Do you have some particularly nice boundary condition, by any chance?